# How to allow user to change app settings and not have to reselect the setting every time they relaunch the app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a app that calculates fees and there's an option to select a different country eg UK Australia etc

```
        this.state = {
              paypalFee: 0.30,
              paypalFeePercentage: 0.029,
              ebayFee: 0.1,
              country: 'US',
              currency: '$'
            };


    //menu option for US users
     <Menu.Item
       onPress={() => this.setState({ ebayFee: parseFloat(0.0915),
       paypalFee: parseFloat(0.30),
       paypalFeePercentage: parseFloat(0.029),
       visible2: false,
       switchOn1: false,
       selected: 'Select Category',
       country: countrys[0],
       currency: currencySign[0] })}
     title={countrys[0]}
     />
     //menu option for UK users
     <Menu.Item
     onPress={() => this.setState({ ebayFee: 0.12,
     paypalFee: parseFloat(0.30),
     paypalFeePercentage: parseFloat(0.029),
     visible2: false,
     switchOn1: false,
     selected: 'Select Category',
     country: countrys[1],
     currency: currencySign[1] })}
   title={countrys[1]}
     />
```

so the way I'm doing it now every time that the user clicks the menu option for there counrty it changes the state of the different fee percentages etc the issue is that everytime the user launches the app they have to select their country how can i have it save that setting for the user i know it might have something to do with async storage but i was trying to use it and was stuck on it for multiple days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage for this, but that's not the best solution either, because this can be cleared by a user. To persist information in a front-end app, usually we use a database. Look into setting up a simple server nodejs and a database (sql or something like mongodb)

Comment: should i use async storage?

Comment: How would i go about using localStorage in this case